# Iterating through rows with "NA" values to create a data frame

Tags: r

I basically have 14 years of data.  Within each year, is anywhere from 100-300 observations of age.

I am trying to create a data frame of all of the ages in one column.
If I try

```
test=data.frame(vals[[1]]$age)
```

I get a data frame of all of the ages of year 1.

If I try

```
for (i in 1:length(survey$years){test=data.frame(vals[[i]]$age)}
```

I get a data frame of the correct number of observations for all of the years, but all "NA" values.

There are "NA" values for some of the observations-- I'm assuming this is the problem, as when I try it with a variable with no NA values (length), it works correctly.  How can I get around the blank values?

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  Maybe `dput(head(YOUR_DATA, 20))`.

Comment: You can use `complete.cases` to omit the NA values.

Comment: Without your data it's a bit hard to say, but something like `na.omit(unlist(test))` might work.

Comment: Why `test=data.frame(vals[[i]]$age)`? That would create a new variable called `test` each time- it wouldn't combine the years in any way.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the NA values. I think it has to do with the for loop.  Please try changing `test=data.frame...` to `test[[i]]=data.frame...` and look at the output of 'test'.  It may answer a lot of questions.

Comment: I don't want all the years separately, as test[[i]] would create, I want them all together in one column.  If I do it with a variable that has no blank values, it works exactly how it should.

Metrics- Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.